# On the definition of a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, curves

I am self studying vector calculus from Hubbard's book [I have no advanced background in topology, differential geometry and related subjects]. Here is the definition of a smooth manifold as per the text.

**A subset M of R^n is a smooth k dimensional manifold if it is the graph of a C1 [continuously differentiable] function f expressing n-k variables as functions of the other k variables.**

Here are my questions about this definition.

1. Why force the function f to be C1? Specifically, why do we need the derivative of f to be continuous? What happens if we allow differentiable functions whose derivative is not continuous?
2. As a follow up, a one dimensional smooth manifold is also called a smooth curve. For a (parameterised) curve to be smooth, is it really true that we require its tangent vector to be non-zero at all points? Do we lose the smoothness property even if the tangent vector at (at least) a single point is zero? Why or why not?

Thanks a lot for reading my question. I understand that I have asked a lot, but these things are bothering me.

Regards,
Madhav

Comment: If you allow zero then the curve defined by $f(t) = (t^3,|t^3|)$ would qualify as "smooth" even though the vertex at $(0,0)$ is a sharp corner which is not considered "smooth".

Comment: Question #1 is a good one. Let's just say things get much more difficult and weird things can happen if we assume anything less than $C^1$. In fact, most differential geometry textbooks assume $C^\infty$, to avoid technical difficulties. As for Question #2, note that the existence of a nonzero-speed parameterization is equivalent to the definition you wrote in bold with $k = 1$.

Comment: Thank you Sam and Deane for answering my question. Consider the curve f(x) = x^2. This function, by definition is at least C1. The parametrization (t, t^2) has nonzero tangent vector everywhere but a different parametrization (t^2, t^4) has a zero tangent vector at the origin (when t=0). Will the parabola still be considered smooth? Is there a difference between a smooth curve and a smooth function? The parabola is smooth (with no parametrization), smooth w.r.t (t, t^2) and not smooth w.r.t (t^2, t^4). Am I correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: A $C^1$ curve is one that has at least one parameterization with nonzero velocity everywhere. Any $C^1$ curve has parameterizations where the velocity is not always nonzero. THe graph of a $C^1$ function is parameterized by $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$, and the corresponding velocity is $(1, f'(x))$, which is always nonzero. So the graph of a $C^1$ function is always a $C^1$ curve.

Comment: Thanks again. Here's a little follow up question. Can there exist a "curve"  that isn't a 1 dimensional manifold but has a parametrization with a nonzero velocity vector everywhere on its domain? Secondly, why do we force parametrizations of manifolds to be 1-1? For example, what could go wrong in parametrizing a unit circle with $(\cos t, \sin t)$ where $\ t $ ranges over all the real numbers instead of restricting it to an interval of length $2\pi .